# Comments not appearing on Trello Development board

Tags: trello-cards, trello-boards

I've just added a [comment](https://trello.com/card/can-t-search-cards-in-closed-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1352) to a card on the [Trello development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) and I can't see my comment.

Looking around other cards on the board, I can't actually see any user comments, just a note stating that a user commented on the card, as shown below

[image: Screen grab of comment problem]

Here is a view from another card with many more missing comments

[image]

I'm using Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m, which it reports as being up-to-date, however a colleague of mine doesn't see the same problem using IE 9. I've just checked in IE9.0.8112.16421, and it works fine for me too.

Is this a known problem? I can't find any other reports of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this, by simply restarting Chrome. I can only assume it was related to something going a bit screwy with the browser (or one of the plugins)

For info, if anyone else has this problem, my plugins are as follows:

- Adblock Plus (Beta) 1.2
- Facebook Disconnect 1.3.0
- Minecraft Wiki Searcher 0.3
- ScrewAds - Block, Skip, Remove YouTube Ads 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but restarting the browser didn't help.

I found out that the Elegant for Trello Extension for Chrome was causing this. I uninstalled Elegant and the comments came back.

Didn't try reinstalling the extension, because I didn't really use it anyway.